# How to resize grid to fit on the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a small game, and I want that to fit on the browser window, without scrolling.
I have a title for the page, and then a grid, with some elements, and I would like to resize these according to the window size.

I've tried to use `<body style="height: 100vh">` and `height: 5%` on the title and `height: 95%` on the grid, but it still overflowed the page, and showed a scroll bar. I also tried using `height: 5vh` and `height: 95vh`on the title and the grid, respectively, but it didnt work either.

I dont have more ideias on what to try, and cant find anything on google.

Here's my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: #007acc;
}

.title {
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 1% auto;
  background: #ff9400;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto auto auto auto auto / 70% 30%;
  grid-gap: 1%;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 1% auto;
}

.music {
  padding: 1%;
  background: grey;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.chat {
  padding: 1%;
  background: white;
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 3 / span 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.input {
  padding: 1%;
  background: gray;
  grid-area: 5 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.chat .name {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.players {
  padding: 1%;
  background: #ffbf00;
  border-radius: 20px;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / span 3 / span 1;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.share {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  grid-area: 4 / 2 / span 2 / span 1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Guess the song</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="music">
        music
      </div>
      <div class="players">
        <h2 style="text-align: center; color: indigo">Players:</h2>
        <p>SamFF</p>
        <p>SamFF</p>
        <p>SamFF</p>
        <p>SamFF</p>
      </div>
      <div class="chat">
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
          <div class="message">
            <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
          </div>
        </div>
        <img class="share" src="images/share.jpg" alt="share">
        <form class="">
          <input type="text" name="" value="">
        </form>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by wrapping your code in a container and give it a grid with relative heights:

```
  .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 100vw;
      grid-template-rows: 70px calc(100vh - 70px);
  }
```

and your html:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background: #007acc;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100vw;
  grid-template-rows: 70px calc(100vh - 70px);
}

.title {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: #ff9400;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto auto auto auto auto / 70% 30%;
  grid-gap: 1%;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 1% auto;
}

.music {
  padding: 1%;
  background: grey;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.chat {
  padding: 1%;
  background: white;
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / span 3 / span 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.input {
  padding: 1%;
  background: gray;
  grid-area: 5 / 1 / span 1 / span 1;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.chat .name {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.players {
  padding: 1%;
  background: #ffbf00;
  border-radius: 20px;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / span 3 / span 1;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.share {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  grid-area: 4 / 2 / span 2 / span 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>Guess the song</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="music">
              music
            </div>
            <div class="players">
              <h2 style="text-align: center; color: indigo">Players:</h2>
              <p>SamFF</p>
              <p>SamFF</p>
              <p>SamFF</p>
              <p>SamFF</p>
            </div>
            <div class="chat">
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
              </div>
              <div class="message">
                <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
                <div class="message">
                  <span class="name">SamFF:</span> Hello world!
                </div>
            </div>
            <img class="share" src="images/share.jpg" alt="share">
            <form class="">
            <input type="text" name="" value="">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```